# How would I test forward voltage?

Tags: voltage, led, multimeter, test

I tried to test an LED but my multimeter only displays 0L. Does anybody know what to do if it doesn’t have a select button?

[image]

Comment: Most DMMs have too low forward voltage to test LEDs. Get yourself a different tester. A select button costs money.

Comment: So nothing i can do except get a new multimeter?

Comment: External current source, which can be as simple as a 9 V battery + a resistor and set your DMM to measure DC voltage instead.

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty easy to measure the forward voltage of an LED with a multimeter, even if the meter can't do it by itself.

You'll need a 9V battery and a resistor - and your LED, of course.

Connect them all like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faEMIx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In place of the voltmeter, use your multimeter to set to read voltage.  Use the 20V DC scale on the multimeter.

The voltage you measure will be the forward voltage of the LED at a little under 10 milliamperes.  That ought to be good enough if you are trying to design a circuit with a typical low current indicator LED.

If your LED is a high current type then you might lower the resistor to 100 ohms or lower.

If your LED is a high voltage type (multiple LEDs in series in one package) then you might need to use a higher voltage.  You can put multiple batteries in series to get the needed voltage.

You **must** in all cases use a current limiting resistor.  For low current LEDs, the resistor will prevent damage to the LED.  For high current LED it will prevent damage to the battery.